# Java generic method overriding

Tags: java, generics, overriding

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public void dosome(Class<? extends Number> c);
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void dosome(Class<Number> c) {}
}
```

From Java docs:
An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
.....
The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.

The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

Is erasure of A

```
dosome(Class<Number> c)?
```

If so what is wrong?

**EDIT1:**
Or if I switch generic type:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public void dosome(Class<Number> c);
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void dosome(Class<? extends Number> c) {}
}
```

What is wrong in this case?

**EDIT2:** I know how to fix it, but I want to understand, what is wrong in this case according java rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to define the concrete argument type in the subclasses depending on a common base type every argument type has to extend, you have to write something like

```
abstract class A<T extends Number> {
    abstract public void dosome(Class<T> c);
}

class B extends A<Number> {
    @Override
    public void dosome(Class<Number> c) {}
}
```

The problem with your code is the special meaning of `? extends Number` describing an "unknown" type with a given "upper bound" which can be used when you don't care or don't be able to obtain the concrete type.

Comment: Is erasure of A dosome(Class<Number> c)?

Comment: In my code piece? No, the erasure depends on the concrete subclass.

Comment: What do you mean "erasure depends on the concrete subclass". If you will not create subclass, erasure will not exists?

Comment: If you do not create subclasses of abstract classes, no objects of these classes will exist. As I wrote, A<T extends Number> means that the concrete erasure depends on the subclass defining the T.

Answer (score 1):

The method `dosome` in the `abstract` class, the caller has the option to invoke any type of `class` as long it a sometype of `Number`

```
abstract public void dosome(Class<? extends Number> c);
```

But you overridden the method like

```
public void dosome(Class<Number> c) {}
```

which will prevent the user from invoking any type of `Number`, meaning you cannot invoke with `integer` type.

By the rules of overriding, you cannot change the `method` parameters.
So,

`Class<? extends Number>` and `Class<Number>` are not the same, its two different type of parameter and that's why its a compiler error.

Comment: Ok, what is wrong if I will switch "? extends Number" like this:        abstract public void dosome(Class<Number> c);   public void dosome(Class<? extends Number> c)

Comment: What you mean more restrictive: paramters, returned type, or access level?